# Join three tables but one two with the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I need to join three tables:

```
A
| ID | Text | Desc |
| 1  | 1234 | one  |
| 2  | 0000 | two  |
```

```
B
| ID | TextID |
| 1  | 1234   |
```

```
C
| ID | TextID |
| 1  |  0000  |
```

and I need in select value Text twice but each time value comes from different join. I need to join table A to table B, and table A to table C.

So the select that I need looks like this:

But I cannot work out how to solve it or join it.
The output should look like this:

```
| desc1 | desc2 | 
|  one  | two   |
```

Comment: Sample data and expected output can help us understand your problem.

Comment: What's the difference between these two `A.Text, A.Text` columns?

Comment: I can't see how those results are even related to each other. They have no relationship.

Comment: They are joined by TextID and Text

Comment: investigate PIVOT

Answer (score 1):

With that data ....

```
WITH
a ( id , txt , dsc ) AS (
          SELECT  1  , 1234 , 'one'
UNION ALL SELECT  2  , 0000 , 'two'
)
,
b (id , textid ) AS (
          SELECT 1  , 1234 
)
,
c(id , textid ) AS (
          SELECT 1  ,  0000  
)
```

You don't really need the other two tables ...

```
SELECT
  MAX(CASE id WHEN 1 THEN dsc END) AS desc1
, MAX(CASE id WHEN 2 THEN dsc END) AS desc2
FROM a                                      
;
```

Result:

```
-- out  desc1 | desc2 
-- out -------+-------
-- out  one   | two
```

Answer (score 1):

With a couple of JOINs you can do it like this:

```
SELECT ISNULL(TableC.id,TableB.id),A1.descr,A2.descr
FROM TableB
FULL JOIN TableC
ON TableB.ID = TableC.ID
LEFT JOIN TableA A1
ON A1.Text = TableB.TextID
LEFT JOIN TableA A2
ON A2.Text = TableC.TextID
```

Comment: table B and table C have nothing in common so you can't join them

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use after join pivot, but there's need to indicate every value after operator IN  ([one],[two]....) ):

```
select [one] as one_column ,[two] as two_column from
(
 select A.Desc from A
 left join B
 on A.ID=B.TextID and A.Text=B.TextID
 left join C
 on A.ID=C.ID and A.Text=C.TextID
)X
PIVOT ( max(X.Desc) For X.Desc in ([one],[two]) ) as piv_tab
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this ?

```
select a1.desc as desc1, a2.desc as desc2 from b, c, a a1, a a2 where b.textid=a1.text and c.textid=a2.text
```

What is unclear is the possible relation between  b and c. Without any we have a full cartesian product of the 2 tables